# FaceTime calls lower system volume

Tags: audio, facetime

When you enter a FaceTime call in OS X, as of Mavericks, it lowers the volume of everything else besides the call. There's no way to disable this "feature." People [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5508201?start=30&tstart=0) suggested disabling audio ducking in Voiceover Utility, but that doesn't have any effect, at least not in Yosemite.

Any suggestions for a hack solution to fix this? I don't want to install some system-wide audio mixer to help, but I'll happily mess with the FaceTime application or some system settings. I'm guessing there's some library it's using to control the system volume, and I'm trying to find a way to prevent the app bundle from accessing it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open FaceTime app (don't make the call yet) and paste the following line into Terminal:

```
printf "p *(char*)(void(*)())AudioDeviceDuck=0xc3\nq" | lldb -n FaceTime
```

and then make the call.

---

Update: for macOS Sierra or higher, replace `FaceTime` with `avconferenced` (https://twitter.com/comex/status/1049459908012195840).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108991/discussion-on-answer-by-david-facetime-calls-lower-system-volume). I’m also putting a lock on comments - this needs a major rewrite to update for SIP. / Catalina / Mojave and other OS versions. Flag for removal of the comment lock if needed.

Comment: If somebody finds a way to make this work with SIP please post a new answer for this.

Answer (score 9):

On current macOS (Mojave and Catalina), System Integrity Protection doesn’t allow modifying the running FaceTime app. You will need to route the audio to another app to remove the ducking or amplify it.

One tool is called [Loopback app](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) from Rogue Amoeba.  In FaceTime app, pick Loopback virtual device as the output so you can get control of the volume.

I am not affiliated with the developer, just a happy user who can't believe how useful this audio app is.

Comment: I think Soundflower would work as a free alternative. Or, in general, any output that's not the same as your default one that you can still hear. I used to use a separate pair of headphones.

Comment: Confirmed Loopback works. You have to add your headphones or whatever as a "monitor" in Loopback is all. It's a great piece of software, btw.

Comment: Mattingalls's Soundflower with mLupine's SoundFlowerbed works too.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it during an active call :)

I noticed it's only audio ducking the other sounds playing on the audio output device selected under FaceTime -> menu bar -> Video -> Output. Usually, "MacBook Pro Speakers" (or "Use System Settings" to the same effect) is the only available one, but if you happen to have an external sound card or headphones and are ok to eg. have the call in the headphones and the normal sounds in the speakers, just select it... *or if not;* a virtual audio device (like [BlackHole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole), open source), that you then could route back to the speakers by eg. setting it as microphone for an audio track in eg. GarageBand with main-speakers as output...

Answer (score -3):

Go into the "Voiceover Utility", go to the "Sound" tab and uncheck "Enable audio ducking" checkbox.

Comment: That only applies to the Voiceover Utility...

Comment: This didn't work

Answer (score -5):

VoiceOver Utility -> Sound -> Disable audio ducking.

Comment: "Audio *ducking*?"

Comment: [just spotted this years later] @Allan *ducking* is the correct audio engineering term for this process. Basically it uses the loudness of one audio source to reduce [duck] another.