# How to prevent FaceTime from muting/quietening system sound?

Tags: macos, catalina, facetime

macOS Catalina 10.15.2 on my MacBook Pro Mid-2015, 15" with Retina display,

I would like to stop FaceTime from making the sounds from other apps (normally music I am playing) quieter.

I tried [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223023/150109) to run

```
printf "p *(char*)(void(*)())AudioDeviceDuck=0xc3\nq" | lldb -n FaceTime
```

but it hasn't been working since Mojave at least