# How to stop FaceTime making other apps quieter?

Tags: macos, monterey, facetime

When I FaceTime call from my Macbook, how can I prevent it from making other apps quieter?

I want to play audio through my speakers at the same volume as always.

[FaceTime calls lower system volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189552/facetime-calls-lower-system-volume) doesn't work anymore

Comment: Possibly related: [FaceTime calls lower system volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189552/facetime-calls-lower-system-volume)

Comment: There are several answers there, and a (slightly hidden) remark on having to disable SIP to make it work. So what exactly have you tried, how did it fail?