# How to stop system audio from being lower when in a FaceTime call?

Tags: macos, monterey, facetime

How can I keep all other apps the same volume as normal when I am in a FaceTime call? On macOS Monterey

Leaving SIP enabled

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to [route the audio through a third party app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314417/5472).

I prefer Rogue Amoeba loopback for this need.

- https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/

Comment: Never tried it for anything like this, but I wonder if [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) [same company] might be a cheaper alternative. As far as I'm aware, both come with free trials to test.

Comment: Yea! @Tetsujin I should try just that on a new build.

Comment: I have it on an M1 iMac on Monterey, but I'd never thought to check this particular functionality, as we just shut all other sound off when using FT.

Comment: Please edit my answer here and also the linked answer with your results :)

Comment: Oh. It just mutes all audio anyway as soon as you initiate a call. [well, saves me having to shut everything up manually in future;) I'd never tested it before, as I have absolutely no desire to have any other 'noise' going on whilst on a call. This iMac has only one mic/speaker source, built-in. idk what might happen if routing was to another device.